# In Neo4J, I keep getting Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError when I try to merge

Tags: neo4j

I am using the *opinions.csv* data from the FossilWorks database for Synapsids.  This is public data.  The *opinions* are links between different taxa and the published works where the opinion is stated.  The *opinions* express relationships like 'It is the scientific opinion of F. Ameghino, as published in '*Première contribution à la connaissance de la faune mammalogique des couches à Pyrotherium*" from 1889, that *Astrapotherium ephebicum* is a species of the genus *Parastrapotherium*.'  In this example, *Parastrapotherium* is the 'parent taxon' and *Astrapotherium ephebicum* is the 'child taxon'.   There are other forms of opinions that do not have a 'parent taxon', so this value is optional.  The file is uses the iso-8859-1 character set, so it was first converted using

iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 references.csv > references.txt

Using Neo4j Desktop (Version: 1.1.5), I can load the references and link it to the child taxa with:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
load csv with headers from "file:///opinions.txt" as row
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
with row where row.status = "belongs to"
match (ref:Reference {reference_no:toInteger(row.reference_no)})
match (child:Taxon {taxon_no:toInteger(row.child_no)})
merge (st:Subtaxon {opinion_no:toInteger(row.opinion_no)})
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(row.pages) = "" then [] else [1] end | SET st.pages = row.pages)
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(row.comments) = "" then [] else [1] end | SET st.comments = row.comments)
merge (ref)-[:DESCRIBES]->(st)
merge (st)-[:CHILD]->(child);
```

However, I was unable to add the parent nodes without getting the rather opaque "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError".  This is the simplest query that will produce the error:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
load csv with headers from "file:///opinions.txt" as row
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
with row where row.status = "belongs to" and row.parent_no is not null
match (parent:Taxon {taxon_no:toInteger(row.parent_no)})
match (st:Subtaxon {opinion_no:toInteger(row.opinion_no)})
merge (st)-[:PARENT]->(parent);
```

I used *csvstat* to verify that parent_no is an integer.   I'm not sure how to efficiently debug this error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Neo4j version 3.4.0  ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Neo4j 3.4.0.  I also found that this is a work around:
using periodic commit
Load csv with headers from "file:///opinions.txt" as row
fieldterminator "|"
with row 
where row.status = "belongs to" 
 and row.parent_no is not null 
 and toInteger(row.parent_no)
match (st:Subtaxon {opinion_no:toInteger(row.opinion_no)})
merge (parent:Taxon {taxon_no:toInteger(row.parent_no)})
 on create set parent.taxon_name = row.parent_name
merge (st)-[:PARENT]->(parent);

This added created 461 nodes, allowing 80757 relationships to be created.  So this is work-around.

Comment: FYI, I add the same prob last week and it's a bug (I haven't investigate more). Just by downgrading to 3.3.4 in my case resolve the problem. But now the 3.4.1 is out, so test with it !

Answer (score 1):

Logisima has the right clue.  I updated from 3.4.0 to 3.4.1 and I was able to load the data.  So this looks to be a bug that was resolved in 3.4.1